# How to config webpack to support for all the condition requirements?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am getting an error : `XMLHttpRequest is not defined` by running the bundled code in nodejs.

in the source code of `axios` it is:

```js
function getDefaultAdapter() {
  var adapter;
  if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined') {
    // For browsers use XHR adapter
    adapter = require('./adapters/xhr');
  } else if (typeof process !== 'undefined' && Object.prototype.toString.call(process) === '[object process]') {
    // For node use HTTP adapter
    adapter = require('./adapters/http');
  }
  return adapter;
}
```

but after bundled by webpack@5, all the conditions get into the same module `13`, This is where the error occurs:

```js
function getDefaultAdapter() {
  var adapter;
  if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined') {
    // For browsers use XHR adapter
    adapter = __webpack_require__(13);
  } else if (typeof process !== 'undefined' && Object.prototype.toString.call(process) === '[object process]') {
    // For node use HTTP adapter
    adapter = __webpack_require__(13);
  }
  return adapter;
}
```

But I really don't know why and how to solve this problem. this is the mini repo: [code-sample](https://github.com/Cinux-Chosan/code-sample)

Answer (score 0):

just set webpack.config.js

```js
{
    // ...
    target: ['web', 'node'],
    // ...
}
```

I thought webpack5 does not support the target attribute, which was obviously my mistake

see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/#string-1